# jQuery select/deselect all limit to 5 from N checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Here below is a function that select or deselect all checkboxes

```
$(function(){    
   $("#selectall").click(function(){$('.case').attr('checked',this.checked);});
      $(".case").click(function() {
         if($(".case").length==$(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked","checked");
         }
         else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
         }
     });
});
```

How can I limit select/deselect all to first 5 checkboxes from example above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
        $('.case:lt(5)').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
    $(".case").click(function () {
        var allfirstChecked = true;

        $('.case:lt(5)').each(function(c, obj){
            if(!$(obj).is(":checked")){
                allfirstChecked = false;
            }
        });

        $("#selectall").prop("checked", allfirstChecked);
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/CK9Em/2/

**Tip:** If you are trying to check/uncheck a checkbox, use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: Edited, please check again...

Comment: Now, checking/unchecking on first 5 checkboxes are affecting on the select all checkbox.

Comment: Yes i now, but i need only for first 5.

Comment: and yeah, this is working only for first 5. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the first 5 `.case`
then use this selector:

`$(".case:lt(5)");`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go...

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectall").click(function() {
        $('.case:lt(5)').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```